# mapping keys and values from a cell array of strings

Tags: matlab, cell-array, keyset

My Data comes back from a database query into matlab as the following:

```
{10000 by 1 cell}
[10000 by 1 double]
[10000 by 1 double]
[10000 by 1 double]
[10000 by 1 double]
```

The first element is a bunch of sharecodes - (not unique, some repeat)

The next four elements are, for example:

```
bids, offers, traded price, close price
```

I use `share_codes = data{1}` which could give me the sharecodes (but they're still a cell)

I want to map the share codes to a number which will allow me to work on them in matrix format.

I can use

```
keySet = {sharecode1, sharecode2, sharecode3}
```

I can use

```
valueSet = [1,2,3]
```

I can use

```
newMap = containers.Map(keySet, valueSet)
```

However I now want to create a new matrix from the `cellarray` i.e. which looks into `data{1}` and now instead of having the `sharecodes` it now has the mapped numbers.

So a cell array which was

```
sharecode1, sharecode2, sharecode3, sharecode2
```

is now a matrix with

```
1, 2, 3, 2
```

I would say the real issue is the first element of the cell array is a bunch of strings.

Answer (score 0):

the cellfun function works and is able to return the strings from data{1} (which was a cellarray) as a coloumn vector in the form of type 'double'

strings_in_numbers = cellfun(@(x),mapObj(x), share_codes)

(found after help from a friend).